# Sending to Shared Contact Group

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm creating a new email from a shared mailbox and trying to add a Contact Group in the Bcc field from the same shared mailbox.

I currently have it working with a test list in my own Contacts, but I can't find if there's a way to reference a shared mailbox group.

Using 
SendTo = "testlist"
and then
.BCC = SendTo

Is there something I can add that will access that shared contact group?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Recipients.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Recipients.Add) method which creates a new recipient in the `Recipients` collection.

```
Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add ("Eugene Astafiev")  
myRecipient.Type = olCC
myRecipient.Resolve()
If Not myRecipient.Resolved Then 
  ' access the shared folder to get the corresponding contacts
End If
```

The [Resolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve) method attempts to resolve a `Recipient object against the Address Book. If it can't be resolved you may try to access the shared contacts folder by using the [GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which returns a Folder object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. So, in the shared folder, you may find the required contacts.

You may find the [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) article helpful.